# JFrame Console Scanner

Tags: java, swing, jframe, java.util.scanner

I have this app that runs in eclipse's console and I want it to run in a jframe.
By that I mean that I want it to ask for name, a and b on the JFrame window and then write something on a file.

It works perfectly in the console but I don't know how to run it as a JFrame.

I want it to look something like this(Image made in photoshop):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQT8F.png
And then automaticaly close

Thanks in advance!

```
some imports...(trying to save space)

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException,IOException {

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    String fileName = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy_HH-mm'.txt'").format(new Date());
    String obs;
    String name;
    String path = "some path";
    int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0;
    System.out.println("input file name");
    name = s.nextLine();
    System.out.println("input a");
    a = s.nextInt();
    System.out.println("input b");
    b = s.nextInt();
    obs = s.nextLine();
    if (a >= 100) {
        d = a / 100;
        c = a % 100;
        b = c;
        a = a + d;
    }
    File file;
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(name)) {
        file = new File(path + fileName);
    } else {
        file = new File(path + name + "#" + fileName);
    }

    FileWriter writer = null;
    try {
        writer = new FileWriter(file);
        writer.write("something");

        if (StringUtils.isBlank(obs)) {
            writer.write("something");
        } else {
            writer.write(obs + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (writer != null)
            try {
                writer.close();
            } catch (IOException ignore) {
            }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html

Comment: You want to run a console in a frame? Or have equivalent functionality using text fields etc?

Comment: @Adam Whatever is easier and more practical.

Comment: Your best solution: don't do it. Trying to force a console program into a GUI is the programming equivalent of trying to force a square peg into a round hole. Yes, it can be done given enough force, but the result will be ugly, will be neither fish nor foul and will be no sort of program that anyone will want to use or maintain.

Comment: Instead gear your GUI program as an event-driven program rather than as a poor kludge to display a console. Your app is small, and so it should be easy to re-write it. Create some JTextFields for user input, create JLabels to tell folks what the text fields are for. Add JButtons so the user can indicate when he's done entering data and is ready for his results. Post the results in a JTextField or JTextArea or JTable or whatever is most appropriate.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels And can I write to a file the given data? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you'll need to do

- separate out your core logic into a separate method that takes String name, int a, int b, ideally in a separate class - then you can reuse from your console version
- Create a basic GUI in a frame with a button to kick off the process
- listen to the button press and call core logic method
- add validation of inputs if necessary
- consider using JFileChooser to allow user to pick the file rather than having to type it in

Example

```
public class ConsoleInFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ConsoleInFrame().showGui();
            }
        });
    }

    public void showGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JTextField file = new JTextField(20);
        JTextField aText = new JTextField(4);
        JTextField bText = new JTextField(4);
        JButton go = new JButton("Go");

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 2));
        panel.add(new JLabel("File"));
        panel.add(file);
        panel.add(new JLabel("a"));
        panel.add(aText);
        panel.add(new JLabel("b"));
        panel.add(bText);

        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(
                new BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

        frame.getContentPane().add(go);

        go.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                process(file.getText(), Integer.parseInt(aText.getText()),
                        Integer.parseInt(bText.getText()));
            }
        });
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void process(String name, int a, int b) {
        String fileName = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy_HH-mm'.txt'")
                .format(new Date());
        String obs;
        String path = "some path";
        int c = 0, d = 0;
        if (a >= 100) {
            d = a / 100;
            c = a % 100;
            b = c;
            a = a + d;
        }
        File file;
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(name)) {
            file = new File(path + fileName);
        } else {
            file = new File(path + name + "#" + fileName);
        }

        FileWriter writer = null;
        try {
            writer = new FileWriter(file);
            writer.write("something");

            if (StringUtils.isBlank(obs)) {
                writer.write("something");
            } else {
                writer.write(obs + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (writer != null)
                try {
                    writer.close();
                } catch (IOException ignore) {
                }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do something like this:

[image]

To do this you have to use `JLabel` to display text: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html

Then to get the input use `JTextField`:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html

And if you want you can use a `JButton` after you write in the `JTextField` to save everything to the file:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html
http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/swing/jbutton.shtml